# Why ngClass does not work?

Tags: angular

I have a parent and a child components:

Parent JS

```
export class ListComponent {
  public users = [{Id: 1, Name: 'One'}, {Id: 2, Name: 'Two'}, {Id: 3, 
Name: 'Three'}];
  public selected = [{Id: 2, Name: 'Two'}];}
```

Parent HTML

```
my-child([users]="users", [selected]="selected")
```

Child JS

```
export class ChildComponent {

@Input() public users: string[];

@Input() public selected: string[];

public isSelected(user.Name) { 
  return this.selected.indexOf(user) !== -1;
}

public clickOnUser(user.Name) {
  if (this.selected.indexOf(user.name) !== -1) {
      this.selected.splice(this.selected.indexOf(user.Name), 1);
    } else {
      this.selected.push(user.Name);
    }
  }

}
```

Child HTML

```
div(*ngFor="let user of users")
  p(
    [ngClass]="{ selected: isSelected(user.Name) }", 
    (click)="clickOnUser(user)") {{user.Name}}
```

I need the second item in a list to be selected by default (I have a class 'selected' in my SASS file for that). For now there's an error in IDE:

"public isSelected(user.Name) {" - dot is highlighted, because comma expected.

"public clickOnUser(user.Name) {" - the same error.

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/rblENbW8RpvNU9g3zgyp?p=preview) we can see almost identical example and it works fine (the difference in this case is in the arrays - they don't contain objects).
So, how to make the second item in my list selected by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**All you need to do is :**

`user.Name` to `user` in your `Template` and `Component`

**Solution to 2nd Object was not selected by default** ,

```
export class ParentComponent {
  public users = [{id: 1, name: 'one'}, {id: 2, name: 'two'}, {id: 3, name: 'three'}];
  public selected = [];

  constructor(){
    this.selected.push(this.users[1]);
  }
}
```

**Reason behind this is very interesting** : **[How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/201183/2349407)**

> As per the doc **[indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)** :
>
> indexOf() compares searchElement to elements of the Array using strict
>   equality (the same method used by the === or triple-equals operator).

**[WORKING DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/vpwMwbWloBVAQTkmkZ2a?p=preview)** (With Array Storing Object)

---

**For More Detail Run The Below Snippet :**

```js
var a = {Id: 2, Name: 'Two'};
var b = {Id: 2, Name: 'Two'};
var c = a;

console.log('Same Obejct But not equal (Not Strickly) --> ' ,a==b);
console.log('Same Obejct But not equal (Strickly) --> ',a===b);
console.log('But Here it will work cause of refernce --> ',a==c);
console.log('Same for Strickly --> ',a===c);
```

Comment: Thank you, but how to make the second element selected by default? It should be red. By the way, in your plunker clicks work fine, but if I click elements in my local app elements remain black.

Comment: Sorry, clicks work as it meant to. But the second element is still not selected by default.